# how to update a variable in matlab?

Tags: matlab, variables, hyperlink, refresh

is there any way to update a variable's value, that depends on another variable?

Look at this simple example:

**CODE:**

```
variable1 = 1;

variable2 = 2 * variable1

variable1 = 3;

variable2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
variable2 =

     2


variable2 =

     2
```

I would like that, after changing the value of variable1, variable2 would change without the need of redefining it like this:

**CODE:**

```
variable1 = 1;

variable2 = 2 * variable1

variable1 = 3;

variable2 = 2 * variable1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
variable2 =

     2

variable2 =

     6
```

Comment: That is simply not how variables work in matlab or any other language for that matter. Some languages support computed properties that do what you request, but I don't know if that is the case for matlab.

Comment: The best option would be to use pointers, which unfortunately Matlab does not support.

Comment: How would pointers fix this? They're useful for exactly aliasing one variable to another, but not recomputing a variable's contents as a function of another's value.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this can't be done automatically in MATLAB.

I would create a script that does all the updating, and call it every time `variable1` is changed.

```
variable1 = 1;
update_vars
```

It's the best way I can think of. It's easy to write, and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to, which you shouldn't, you could make `variable2` etc into functions, and use `evalin` to get the current value of `variable1`:

```
variable2 = @() 2 * evalin('caller', 'variable1')
variable1 = 1;
variable2() % output: 2
variable1 = 15;
variable2() % output: 30
```

This is a rather ugly solution and I would not use it myself. If your code is in a function there is a slightly better solution (in the sense that it doesn't use eval):

```
function [ ... ] = myFun( ... )
variable1 = 1;
variable2() % output: 2
variable1 = 15;
variable2() % output: 30
    function v2 = variable2; v2 = 2 * variable1; end
end
```

Still, I would personally use something similar to Robert P's `update_vars` script. Again if you are in a function you could use the fact that [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) can access and modify all variables in their parent:

```
function [ ... ] = myFun( ... )
variable1 = 1;
updateVars();
variable2 % 2
variable1 = 15;
updateVars();
variable2 % 30

    function updateVars
        variable2 = 2 * variable1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned (less specifically) in one of the comments, this kind of behaviour is possible by creating a class with dependent properties that are calculated "on-the-fly". An example:

```
classdef ReplaceWithAMeaningfulName < handle
    properties (Dependent)
        data % The property that holds the instance's main value
    end

    properties (Dependent, SetAccess = private) % Only get-access, please
        someCalculatedValue % Something calculated
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        m_data % The private storage for data property
    end

    methods
        function self = ReplaceWithAMeaningfulName(data)
            % Constructor
            if nargin > 0
                self.data = data;
            end
        end

        % Property accessors for data property
        function set.data(self, value)
            assert(isnumeric(value), [mfilename ':InvalidValue'], ...
                'Value for property ''data'' must be numeric.');
            self.m_data = value;
        end

        function value = get.data(self)
            value = self.m_data;
        end

        % Property accessor for your calculated value
        function value = get.someCalculatedValue(self)
            value = self.data * 2;
        end
    end
end
```

Now, you can use it as follows

```
>> x = ReplaceWithAMeaningfulName(123);
>> x.someCalculatedValue

ans =

   246

>> x.data = 500;
>> x.someCalculatedValue

ans =

        1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you don't want to use a function?

```
function [Out1, Out2] =  setVariables(Arg1);
   Out1 = Arg1;
   Out2 = 2*Arg1;
end


[Variable1, Variable2] = setVariables(2)
```

or use syms (of course this can be done with function too)

```
syms Variable2(d);
Variable2(d) = 2*d;

Variable2(Variable1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eval function :

```
variable2 = eval('2*eval(''variable1'')')
```

Comment: Nope - this only gets evaluated once when variable2 is assigned; it'll have the exact same behavior as `variable2 = 2 * variable1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get very close by changing `variable2` from a regular variable to a nested function. In Matlab, variables and function calls have identical syntax (a variant of the "uniform access principle"), so you can make a direct replacement. This works in your case because a nested function in Matlab is a "closure", in that it has access to live, updated values of all the variables in the enclosing workspace.

This only works inside a function, not a script or at the command line.

```
function foo

v1 = 1;

% Define v2 in terms of the "live" v1 value
function v2_val = v2()
v2_val = 2 * v1;
end

v2  % evaluates to 1
v1 = 3;
v2  % evaluates to 6

end
```